# Python 2.x and 3.x compatible code for sending byte data over JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, base64

I have a string that is base-64 encoded.

```
some_s = base64.encodestring(....)
```

In Python 2.7 I can serialize such a string to JSON (json.dumps).

In Python 3.3 'some_s' is a byte string and needs to be convertered to 'str first:

```
some_s2 = str(some_s2, encoding='ascii')
```

Then some_s2 can be serialized to JSON.

Unfortunately Python 2.7 does not accept the encoding parameter as part of the str() call.

How would you write the conversion code here that runs both with Python 2.7 and Python 3.3?

Comment: Why so many down votes? This seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 5):

You can *detect* that your value is not of type `str`:

```
some_s = base64.encodestring(....)
if not isinstance(some_s, str):
    some_s = some_s.decode('ascii')
```

Only in Python 3 is `some_s` of type `bytes`. Note the `.decode()` method as well, instead of `str(some_s, encoding='ascii')`, which would work in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Ah, it's you. That's what you get for using a silly 'anonymous' name, you get advice from me. Yes, in this case, type detection is your best option.